# Udisks2, LUKS and btrfs

Tags: btrfs, luks, dm-crypt, udisks, enlightenment

I just bought a portable USB HDD,on which i put 2 partitions : a LUKS one, which contains a btrfs fs and a fat32 one, in case I'd have to use a system which doesn't support LUKS or btrfs

I use enlightenment as my DM, and therefore, the enlightenment file manager.
When I plug my hdd, on the desktop, appears only the fat32 one.

I've figured out enlightenment uses udisk2 to mount removable devices.

So I ask, is there a way for udisks2 to mount LUKS encrpted volumes ? Or is the problem because I'm using btrfs which is quite new ?

the partition mounts well using

```
 mount -t auto
```